# Convert numpy array to tuple

Tags: python, numpy

**Note:** This is asking for the reverse of the usual tuple-to-array conversion.

I have to pass an argument to a (wrapped c++) function as a nested tuple.  For example, the following works

```
X = MyFunction( ((2,2),(2,-2)) )
```

whereas the following *do not*

```
X = MyFunction( numpy.array(((2,2),(2,-2))) )
X = MyFunction( [[2,2],[2,-2]] )
```

Unfortunately, the argument I would like to use comes to me as a numpy array.  That array always has dimensions 2xN for some N, which may be quite large.

Is there an easy way to convert that to a tuple?  I know that I could just loop through, creating a new tuple, but would prefer if there's some nice access the numpy array provides.

If it's not possible to do this as nicely as I hope, what's the prettiest way to do it by looping, or whatever?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

```
>>> arr = numpy.array(((2,2),(2,-2)))
>>> tuple(map(tuple, arr))
((2, 2), (2, -2))
```

Comment: So for a simple 1-d array `tuple(arr)`

Answer (score 39):

Here's a function that'll do it:

```
def totuple(a):
    try:
        return tuple(totuple(i) for i in a)
    except TypeError:
        return a
```

And an example:

```
>>> array = numpy.array(((2,2),(2,-2)))
>>> totuple(array)
((2, 2), (2, -2))
```

Comment: Nice generalization.  As a python newbie, though, I wonder if it's considered good style to use exceptions for a condition that is almost as common as the non-exceptional state.  At least in c++, flow control by exceptions is usually frowned upon.  Would it be better to test if `type(a)==numpy.ndarray`?

Comment: This is pretty common in python because of the concept of "duck-typing" and EAFT, more here: http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-duck-typing. The advantage of this approach is that it'll convert any nested sequence into nested tuples, not just an array. One thing I should have done that I've fixed is specify which errors I want handled by the except block.

Comment: In C++, exceptions are slow relative to conditionals for a variety of reasons. In Python, they are approximately the same in terms of performance - this is one of the places that we have to check our C++ intuitions at the door.

Comment: This solution is 100% what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

I was not satisfied, so I finally used this:

```
>>> a=numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

>>> tuple(a.reshape(1, -1)[0])
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

I don't know if it's quicker, but it looks more effective ;)

Comment: That was not the shape that I wanted for the tuple.

Comment: This looks like it can be a nice 0-copy way to hash arrays

Comment: Nah. It takes the same time (pardon the ugly formatting):


# %%
import numpy as np
n = 10000
a = np.array([list(range(n)) for i in range(n)])

# %%
%timeit hash(tuple(map(tuple, a)))
>>> 3.59 s ± 70.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# %%
%timeit hash(tuple(map(tuple, a)))
>>> 3.53 s ± 47.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Answer (score 9):

Another option

```
tuple([tuple(row) for row in myarray])
```

If you are passing NumPy arrays to C++ functions, you may also wish to look at using Cython or SWIG.

Comment: That doesn't convert to tuple. Converts to a list?

Comment: Did you try it? It makes a tuple when I run in. Note that the last function called is tuple, which returns a tuple. If you have only the [...] part without the outer tuple, you will get a list of tuples.

Comment: is there a faster method?

Comment: You could avoid creating the intermediate `list` by omitting the square brackets, i.e. using `tuple(tuple(row) for row in myarray)`

Answer (score 5):

If you like long cuts, here is another way
tuple(tuple(a_m.tolist()) for a_m in a )

```
from numpy import array
a = array([[1, 2],
           [3, 4]])
tuple(tuple(a_m.tolist()) for a_m in a )
```

The output is 
((1, 2), (3, 4))

Note just (tuple(a_m.tolist()) for a_m in a ) will give a generator expresssion. 
Sort of inspired by @norok2's comment to  [Greg von Winckel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23414424/12226486)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution to `tuple`-ify an arbitrary nested iterable sequence,

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable
import numpy as np

npArr = np.array(((2,2),(2,-2)))

def func(val):
    if not isinstance(val, Iterable):
        return val
    return tuple(func(elem) for elem in val)

# # One-liner
# func = lambda val: tuple(func(elem) for elem in val) if isinstance(val, Iterable) else val

res = func(npArr)
print(f"{res = }")
```