# Numpy concatenation of two 2D arrays while keeping data separate

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have NUMPY arrays A and B:

```
A = [
    [1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 1 ,1, 1, 5, 0, 7, 8, 3],
    ..etc
]

B = [
    [1, 2 ,3],
    [1, 0 ,1],
    ..etc
]
```

Both 2D arrays have the same number of lines. I would like to have create array C :

```
C = [
    [ [1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2 ,3] ],
    [ [1, 1 ,1, 1, 5, 0, 7, 8, 3], [1, 0 ,1] ],
    ..etc
]
```

I would also like to know how i can do the opposite. meaning, go from C to A and B. I have tried functions like append, concatenate and stack. but i can't figure out how to this.

Comment: Do you want C to be a 2D array? Or 3D? What shape are you trying to show here for C? Because numpy does not support ragged arrays, and that's what you're showing.

Comment: Why do you need to create this `C`?  Does it help with subsequent processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `zip()` them:

```
A = [
    [1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 1 ,1, 1, 5, 0, 7, 8, 3],
]

B = [
    [1, 2 ,3],
    [1, 0 ,1],
]

C = list(map(list, zip(A, B)))
```

C will be:

```
[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3]],
 [[1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 7, 8, 3], [1, 0, 1]]]
```

Comment: i'm sorry i had forgotten a part of the C matrix .. i modified my question .. also i need a numpy solution as it's a numpy array

Comment: @MohamedBenkedadra numpy isn't really great with different sized elements. If you want nested lists you can just not use `chain`. See edit. You can pass the to numpy with `numpy.array(C)` you will get an array of lists, though,

Comment: thank you, the solution works but takes a long time because i have millions on entries and i need a faster one

Answer (score 1):

I have updated my code and applied something similar to what's mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54934345/merge-two-numpy-arrays-into-a-list-of-lists-of-tuples):

```
import numpy as np
A = [
[1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[1, 1 ,1, 1, 5, 0, 7, 8, 3]
]

B = [
[1, 2 ,3],
[1, 0 ,1]
]

aArray=np.array(A)
bArray=np.array(B)

x_z = map(tuple,aArray)
y_z = map(tuple,bArray)
cArray=[list(i) for i in zip(x_z, y_z)]
cArray
```

The Output:

```
[[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (1, 2, 3)],
 [(1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 7, 8, 3), (1, 0, 1)]]
```

Comment: i'm sorry i had forgotten a part of the C matrix .. i modified my question .. also i need a numpy solution as it's a numpy array

Comment: Alright @Mohamed Benkedadra, please have a look at my updated code

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to your description, `A` and `B` are lists

```
In [414]: A = [ 
     ...:     [1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
     ...:     [1, 1 ,1, 1, 5, 0, 7, 8, 3]]                                                             
In [415]: B = [ 
     ...:     [1, 2 ,3], 
     ...:     [1, 0 ,1]]
```

As others show, it is easy to use `zip` to interleave the elements of these 2 lists:

```
In [416]: C = [[a,b] for a,b in zip(A,B)]                                                              
In [417]: C                                                                                            
Out[417]: 
[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3]],
 [[1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 7, 8, 3], [1, 0, 1]]]
```

If you want `C` to be an array, you need to create an object dtype array of the right size, and fill it:

```
In [418]: C = np.empty((2,2),object)                                                                   
In [419]: C[:,0] = A                                                                                   
In [420]: C[:,1] = B                                                                                   
In [421]: C                                                                                            
Out[421]: 
array([[list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), list([1, 2, 3])],
       [list([1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 7, 8, 3]), list([1, 0, 1])]], dtype=object)
```

However if `A` was really an array, this assignment would not work:

```
In [422]: C[:,0] = np.array(A)                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-422-d1283e1b548a> in <module>
----> 1 C[:,0] = np.array(A)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,9) into shape (2)
```

It's not impossible to assign an array `A` to this object `C`, but it's tricky.

As for the reverse

```
In [425]: C[:,0]                                                                                       
Out[425]: 
array([list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
       list([1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 7, 8, 3])], dtype=object)
```

A more natural way of combining arrays like `A` and `B` is:

```
In [424]: np.hstack((A,B))                                                                             
Out[424]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 7, 8, 3, 1, 0, 1]])
```

In that new array `A` and `B` loose their identity, though it's easy to recover them with indexing:

```
In [426]: np.hstack((A,B))[:,:-3]                                                                      
Out[426]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 7, 8, 3]])
```

In short, your desired `C` is somewhat ambiguous, and not the most natural `numpy` structure.  The original list zip is not inferior - it might even be faster.

===

Playing around with these lists, I found that

```
In [430]: np.array((A,B))                                                                              
Out[430]: 
array([[list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
        list([1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 7, 8, 3])],
       [list([1, 2, 3]), list([1, 0, 1])]], dtype=object)
```

This a (2,2) object array of lists.  And transposing it produces the same array as in [421]:

```
In [431]: _.T                                                                                          
Out[431]: 
array([[list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), list([1, 2, 3])],
       [list([1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 7, 8, 3]), list([1, 0, 1])]], dtype=object)
```

But trying to do the same with arrays, I hit the same error as in [422].  In fact [422] might explain this error:

```
In [432]: np.array((np.array(A),np.array(B)))                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-432-a4327b98cfe7> in <module>
----> 1 np.array((np.array(A),np.array(B)))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,9) into shape (2)
```

If `A` and `B` match in shape, `np.array((A,B))` is a 3d array.  Often when the inputs differ in shape, the result is an object dtype array.  But for some combinations, such as this, it raises an error.  So `np.array((A,B))` is not a reliable way of making an object dtype array.