# How can I convert an array inside a python dictionary to a tuple?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, tuples, numpy-ndarray

I have this dictionary:

```
{
    0: array([-0.16638531, -0.11749843]),
    1: array([-0.2318372 ,  0.00917023]),
    2: array([-0.42934129, -0.0675385 ]),
    3: array([-0.63377579, -0.02102854]),
    4: array([-0.26648222, -0.42038916]),
    5: array([-0.17250316, -0.73490218]),
    6: array([-0.42774336, -0.61259704]),
    7: array([-0.55420825, -0.77304496]),
    8: array([0.13900166, 0.07800885]),
    9: array([0.42223986, 0.16563338]),
    10: array([ 0.39895669, -0.09198566]),
    12: array([0.24324618, 0.44829616]),
    11: array([ 0.55394714, -0.17960723]),
    13: array([0.192127 , 0.5988793]),
    14: array([0.39554203, 0.7186038 ]),
    15: array([0.53721604, 1.        ])
}
```

I want to convert those numpy.ndarray values to tuples, and have something like this:

```
{
    0: (-0.16638531, -0.11749843),
    1: (-0.2318372 ,  0.00917023),
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10016379/14316282) it looks like for each value in the dictionary you can:

```
tuple(arr)
```

So for the whole dictionary you can probably do something like:

```
 new_dict = {key: tuple(arr) for key, arr in old_dict.items()}
```

Or easier to understand:

```
new_dict = {}
for key, arr in old_dict.items():
    new_dict.update({key: tuple(arr)})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mapping = { key: (item[0], item[1]) for key, item in your_dict.items() }
```

Comment: Tested and got this TypeError: tuple expected at most 1 argument, got 2. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Indeed. A tuple call must have only a single iterable argument. Thanks for the info, edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension.

Python dictionaries have an `.items()` method that return a tuple of (key, value) for each key-value pair.

The comprehension recreates a new mapping with the original key and the `array` cast as a `tuple`.

```
from numpy import array

data = {
    0: array([-0.16638531, -0.11749843]),
    1: array([-0.2318372 ,  0.00917023]),
    2: array([-0.42934129, -0.0675385 ]),
    3: array([-0.63377579, -0.02102854]),
    4: array([-0.26648222, -0.42038916]),
    5: array([-0.17250316, -0.73490218]),
    6: array([-0.42774336, -0.61259704]),
    7: array([-0.55420825, -0.77304496]),
    8: array([0.13900166, 0.07800885]),
    9: array([0.42223986, 0.16563338]),
    10: array([ 0.39895669, -0.09198566]),
    12: array([0.24324618, 0.44829616]),
    11: array([ 0.55394714, -0.17960723]),
    13: array([0.192127 , 0.5988793]),
    14: array([0.39554203, 0.7186038 ]),
    15: array([0.53721604, 1.        ])
}

print({key: tuple(value) for key, value in data.items()})
```

OUTPUT:
`{0: (-0.16638531, -0.11749843), 1: (-0.2318372, 0.00917023), 2: (-0.42934129, -0.0675385), 3: (-0.63377579, -0.02102854), 4: (-0.26648222, -0.42038916), 5: (-0.17250316, -0.73490218), 6: (-0.42774336, -0.61259704), 7: (-0.55420825, -0.77304496), 8: (0.13900166, 0.07800885), 9: (0.42223986, 0.16563338), 10: (0.39895669, -0.09198566), 12: (0.24324618, 0.44829616), 11: (0.55394714, -0.17960723), 13: (0.192127, 0.5988793), 14: (0.39554203, 0.7186038), 15: (0.53721604, 1.0)}`